# Showing html content on sharing post on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

It is showing the html content on sharing the post on facebook, only the text with hyperlink should display, Facebook post should display as it is originally, showing html content (`<b>,<h1>,<a>`) is not the correct way of facebook post

[image]

There must be some setting on Facebook or something else

I have added below meta tags under head tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta id="m1" runat="server" property="og:title" content="" />
<meta id="m2" runat="server" property="og:description" content="" />
<meta id="m3" name="og:image" runat="server" property="og:image" content="" />
<meta id="m4" name="og:url" runat="server" property="og:url" content="" />
```

let me know, if doing anything wrong

Comment: if the link oyu are referencing in a Facebook post has meta tags in the HTML then Facebook will automatically display a preview of that lilnk in the post.  That's what it does

Comment: Thanks Scott, I have added above meta tags, but still not suceed